# How do you change the style of the Title tag in css?

Tags: css

My example:

**HTML**:

```
<title>hello</title>
```

**CSS** (that I'd like to apply):

```
title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**Output**:

```
<title>HELLO</title>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The [`title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) tag is filed under the [Metadata category](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Metadata_content). As such, any CSS changes won't apply to it since the `title` is never actually "rendered" on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The title tag is not formatted text. If JavaScript is an option you can use: `document.title = document.title.toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 1):

You can apply CSS to the  element, but not though the style attribute (since it is for "[All elements but BASE, BASEFONT, HEAD, HTML, META, PARAM, SCRIPT, STYLE, TITLE](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html)").

I'm not aware of any browser that will apply CSS for the rendering of the title in browser tabs or title bars though.

You can, however, do something like:

`head { display: block; }
title { display: block; font-size: 200%; font-weight: bold; }`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the head tag is stylable. if you really can't just add the uppercase in html you could do it in javascript but I highly recommend just typing the string in uppercase.

Comment: This is on a subreddit theme, and so I do not have access to js

Comment: contact the subreddit owner, you cannot do this only with css.

Comment: I am the subreddit owner and reddit does not allow us to put in custom js functions.

Comment: Then the only way to do it is to put the subreddit name in uppercase :/